# get 400 bad request in a simple rest api get method

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have this in customerController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetCustomerNames")]
[Route("api/accounts/myDept/customer/GetCustomerNames", Name = "Get_CustomerNames")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomerNames()
{
```

...}

in Register.cs
I have this

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config, IUnityContainer container)
{
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                  name: "Get_CustomerNames",
                  routeTemplate: "api/accounts/myDept/{controller}/{action}",
                  defaults: null,
                  constraints: null,
                  handler: defaultHandlers);
}
```

in fiddler, I use GET http://localhost:5426/api/accounts/myDept/customer/GetCustomerNames

I get 400 bad request.

I must have missed something.  Please let me know.  thanks

Comment: route declaration is api/accounts/myDept/customer/GetCustomerNames.  Did you forget the "customer" part in your fiddler request?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  updated.  controller is customerController.cs  thanks

Comment: Any reason you are defining the route twice -- once in the Register method and once in the attribute?  Have you enabled attribute routing? Have you set a RoutePrefix attribute on the customerController class?

Comment: Oh, No. I am new to rest api.  Can you explain in detail or give some example? Thanks

Comment: @dbugger What is the right way?  I simply copied existing methods.

Comment: Either works fine in webapi2-- but you don't need both.

Comment: Put the route back to default in Register.cs, then add this: config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

Comment: I think I must have done something wrong.  I put config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()  before config.EnsureInitialized(); and then get exception InvalidOperationException